# How to force items of the last row of a flexbox, to pick all remaining height (in flex-row mode)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider that we have this code (**Please test it**):

```css
.x{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: start;
    background-color: #0bd;
    width: 420px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: auto;
 }
 .x>*{
    width: 25%;
    height: 45px;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .N, .L {
     width: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='x'>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div class='N'>N</div>
    <div class='L'>L</div>
</div>
```

I need something like this:

```css
.x{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
  background-color: #0bd;
  width: 420px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.x>*{
  width: 25%;
  height: 45px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.N, .L {
     width: 50%;
}
.N {
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class='x'>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div class='N'>N</div>
  <div class='L'>L</div>
</div>
```

**Important Points:**

1. We must use `flex-flow: row`.
2. The `.N` (N class) must fill all remaining space vertically (remaining height).
3. We should not use nested elements. (**And we can not change this HTML code not at all. we must play with its pure `css` only.**).
4. The only option in our case is `flex-box`.
5. We can not use constant `height` or `calc(100% - xxx)`, because we have not `xxx`.
6. We may have more than two lines and `.N` may appear in the third line (or fourth, ...).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do the main wrapper element `width` and `height` are constants? Or it could be the viewport size or whatever manual size? And also, * fill all remaining space vertically* of its viewport? Or window viewport?

Comment: Thanks @SMAKSS. All parts have dynamic size. we don't know size of them in designing level. based on the second snippet, the '.N' elem must fill remaining space of its parent that distinguished by `#f0f` color (the flex element). if we set its height to 100%, the vertical scroll appears that is not correct.

Comment: We are developing a framework, and this is a very simplified example of our need. It is naturally not possible to explain all the details here. Suppose we want to allow the developer of the second step to place elements before and after our elements ... The elements of the last row (.N & .L) must occupy the remainder of the height. Our structure must necessarily be `flex-flow: row` and without nested elements (because of an intra-system concept).

Comment: Try adding `display: flex; align-items: stretch;` in *N class* and remove height from it.

Comment: Thanks @isAif; but i have tested this before and it did not help.

Comment: Well, AFAIK, there is no possible approach through pure CSS and flexbox to overcome this situation unless you change the flow to the column, otherwise, this is not achievable. But since you got the dynamic size for each box, one of the possible workarounds could be calculating the box size of the first *(`.N` previous rows)* row with JS and then calculate the `.N` element height with `CSS#calc` property. Other than the flexbox approach, you can achieve this with grid system easily.

Comment: Thanks again @SMAKSS. I have implemented this with 'flex-flow: column' or nested elements but this is not possible in our case. it is also not possible to use 'js' or 'grid'. thanks for your comments.

Comment: Indeed not possible with flexbox. This is what Css-grid is designed for

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D; That's right, but I was hoping someone would come up with a solution.